# Swift client library for Google cloud pubsub

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-pubsub

I am doing RND on Google pubsub. I want to implement the same in iOS , but in swift4. From [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-pubsub-discuss/T9nV19C9Woc) link I found that Google has only Objective C client for iOS. On the basis of this I have some queries

1] From [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest) link (in objective c client), they have added `GTMAppAuth` pod in their sample project. Can we use the same pod for swift4 also?

2] If no, do we have any other option available to access Google pubsub events in swift4 ?